# how to prevent lite-server from opening browser window on startup?

Tags: node.js, npm, lite-server

I'm using the `lite-server` with `npm run lite`

my config file,

```
module.exports = {
    "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
};
```

whenever I start the server, it opens up a new browser window. How do I prevent lite server opening browser window on server startup?

thanks.

Comment: `lite-servers` uses `browserSync`, it might help you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems like `browserSync` has option `open: false`

https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-open

try in your `bs-config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    "server": { "baseDir": "./src" },
    "open": false
};
```

Or in `bs-config.json` in your project's folder:

```
{
   "server": { "baseDir": "./src" },
   "open": false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Lite-server uses

`BrowserSync`

And allows for `configuration overrides` via a local

```
bs-config.json
```

or

```
 bs-config.js
```

file in your project.

The default behavior of the server `serves from the current folder`, `opens a browser`, and applies an HTML5 route fallback to `./index.html.` so we need to set the configuration

For example, to change the server port, watched file paths, and base directory for your project, create a `bs-config.json` in your `project's folder:`

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "files": ["./src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
}
```

So for browser not opening you have to set like this

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "files": ["./src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" },
  "open":false
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this when lite-server is used with concurrently (as in angular 2's "starter kit")?

Comment: @dragonmnl I think it depends on the files and folder structure you should come up with `baseDir` option as stated above change it according to your app structure and modify the `files`

Comment: the thing is lite server is run without any specific option with concurrently package. I'm not sure how it works.  my goal would be knowing where to put lite server's config file

Comment: @dragonmnl at the root of application you keep the configurations file